# Rails parameters, why the params[:key] syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to manually create some params to pass to a Rails controller function, why are keys to the params hash listed with the colon, e.g. `params[:key]` and not `params["key"]`?

Comment: Are you saying that :key is the same as "key" for hash data structures?

Comment: :starts_a_symbol while "quotes_delimit_strings".  when rails parses the request header, it builds the params hash with symbols.

Comment: OK, if rails is say extracting an id from params, then why is it params[:id] and not params["id"]?

Comment: because the keys to that hash are symbols.  hash can use any kind of object as key or value.  symbols are commonly used as keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rails uses [ActiveSupport’s `HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-c-new) for almost all hashes that come from within itself, such as `params`. A `HashWithIndifferentAccess` behaves the same as a regular hash except key access by symbol or string of the same “value” returns the same hash value. For example:

```
h = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
h[:foo] = 'bar'
h[:foo]  #=> "bar"
h['foo'] #=> "bar"

h['foo'] = 'BAR'
h[:foo]  #=> "BAR"
```

vs. a normal hash:

```
h = {}
h[:foo] = 'bar'
h[:foo]  #=> "bar"
h['foo'] #=> nil

h['foo'] = 'BAR'
h[:foo]  #=> "bar"
```

This allows you to not have to worry (for better or worse) about whether a particular key was a Symbol or a String.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes uses symbols as keys because there is always only one instance of each symbol, which cause easier search. When using string it hash must be computed because it can not be the same string (another instance, but with the same content). So it make it faster. The active support `HashWithIndifferentAccess` will cast all strings to symbols using `#to_sym` method.

Comment: Actually, it’s the other way around: [`HashWithIndifferentAccess` internally converts symbol keys to strings](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb#L163).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases strings (with quotes) and symbols (with a colon) are interchange as Hash keys in Rails. Symbols for Hash keys is idiomatic when they are predefined constants. Ruby 1.9 has syntactic sugar for writing Hashes with symbols for keys.